# How to use plural string resource with glance appWidget?

Tags: android, kotlin, glance-appwidget

How to apply my plural string resources in widget?
There is no such extension in context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case somebody also will need this.
Now I managed to get plurals resources through app context like this

```
context.applicationContext.resources.getQuantityString(R.plurals.month,
number, number)
```

I know this is temp solution, I hope Glance team will continue to develop their product.